# Shutdown keyboard shortcut on MacBook Pro with Touchbar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

So on previous Apple computers, one could shutdown using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Option + Cmd + Eject/Power`. However, the new MacBook Pro w/ Touchbar has neither an eject nor a power key. Does this mean that the shortcut no longer exists for this computer?

Comment: why would you add a shutdown icon when the Touch ID button is a power button already?

Comment: @JBallin pressing the TouchID button does not shutdown the computer.

Comment: Really? You held it down for a while?

Comment: Anyways you don't need to shut down these new MBP's. You can just put them to sleep, that's probably why it isn't an option on touch bar.

Comment: @JBallin What do you mean specifically by that? Are you saying that they are efficient enough not to need shutdown?

Comment: See new answer addressing both Touch ID power button and necessity of shut down.

Comment: I actually managed to get the shortcut working using an external apple keyboard (I.e: has an eject button) so the combination itself still works, we are just missing the key for the eject button; now I know there is an option to create custom quick actions in the touchbar, so if we manage to create a custom quick action that basically clicks the missing eject key, we might be able to recreate the behavior using a custom touchbar action, I'll research the matter and post an answer if I'll succeed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Customize TouchID Control Strip]

Unfortunately it's not an option. There is an option for a sleep command, but there is nothing for Shut Down or Restart. Modifier/command keys on the sleep button don't work either.

Comment: Maybe a bit unrelated but I wonder why the Touch ID sensor is a button (i.e. it depresses). It doesn't work in my shutdown shortcut unfortunately.

Comment: @Amja the reason that the button depresses is so that you can power it on after a shutdown while the lid was open. It also acts as a force shut down button when you hold it for about 10 seconds, but you should only use this in emergencies.

Comment: I just tried adding the sleep button and various key combinations (command, shift, option, control) hoping something would trigger a shutdown but as of 10.12.3 -- nothing appears to work.

Answer (score 2):

[Build custom keyboard shortcut to bring up shutdown dialogue (apple.stackexchange)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262027/keyboard-shortcut-for-powering-down-2016-macbook-pro-with-touch-bar)

[Touch ID button shuts down the computer (Apple Support)](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207054) Another button on touch bar would be redundant.

> Unlike with older Mac notebooks, holding down Touch ID on your 2016
>   MacBook Pro doesn't display a dialog with options to Sleep, Restart,
>   or Shut Down. You can find these options in the Apple menu. If your
>   MacBook Pro is unresponsive, you can hold down Touch ID for six
>   seconds to force a shut down. Note that you'll lose any unsaved work
>   if you do this.

[Shutting down your 2016 MBP is not required unless not using for 36 hours (apple.stackexchange)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128065/how-often-should-one-shutdown-a-macbook-instead-of-just-closing-the-lid)

Comment: Don't think it is redundant if I need to shutdown, but not a hard shutdown (because the machine isn't unresponsive nor I want to make any mess). And yes, I can leave the machine on, but I don't want to do it always. So this info does not answer the question either.
The first link you post here, the keyboard shortcut, sounds interesting to bring that dialogue back. Thank you for that info. But I guess you have to select in Touchbar options to show Functions.

Comment: @leon 1. You can set it so that holding `fn` key will show function keys on the touch bar. 2. You could set a keyboard shortcut that doesn't involve the touchbar.

Comment: thank you, JBallin. A good approach. Similar to it, I opted to use fn to show quick-actions and integrated there the shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a sleep or shutdown button to the touch bar in system preferences > keyboard > (set touchbar options - it's not called this but I can't recall the option name, it's toward the bottom of the screen) and then drag whichever optional button you desire to the touchbar

Comment: There is a sleep option but sadly no shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shutdown button on Touch Bar (except hard poweroff), just a sleep button as customizable option, but we can add a QuickAction with Automator with a shutdown Script and assign a button on the Touchbar. I made a nice red "OFF" button. I wrote the detailed workflow and script to make it in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251390862, taking the programming from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8263239.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using Shortcuts shell script

I'm encountering this having just bought a Magic Keyboard Extended with Touch ID for my M1 Mac Mini. After I finished being dumbfounded that these shortcuts were removed, I found this to be a good current (macOS 14 Sonoma) solution using Shortcuts and the `sudo shutdown` command:

1. Open Shortcuts on your Mac and create a new shortcut; name it "Shutdown Mac".
2. Add a **Run Shell Script** action to the shortcut, replace the script body with `/sbin/shutdown now`, and check the **Run as Administrator** checkbox.
3. Click the info ℹ️ button at the top of the right sidebar, and add a keyboard shortcut.

- You can't assign shortcuts to the Touch Id button, so the next best thing with the extended keyboard is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F13</kbd>
- Adding a shortcut will automatically select the **Use as Quick Action** and **Services Menu** checkboxes

4. To prevent the shortcut from showing in the Services menu elsewhere, set the shortcut to receive **No** input.

When you're done, you'll have a shortcut that looks like this (<kbd>fn</kbd> is the  key now, and using <kbd>F13</kbd> automatically includes <kbd>fn</kbd>, hence the  in the keyboard shortcut in the image; it's intuitive ):

[image: shutdown shortcut window]

**For a restart shortcut**, repeat the process, naming the shortcut "Restart Mac" and using `/sbin/shutdown -r now` as the shell script body.

Now close the shortcut and test out either keyboard shortcut. You'll be prompted for Touch Id or administrator password, and then your machine will promptly shut down or restart. In my opinion, having restart/shutdown protected by Touch Id a nice addition.

---

* Note this is not as "soft" of a shutdown/restart as when using those options from the  menu. This will STFD, force-quitting all processes.