# Keyboard shortcut for powering down MacBook Pro with Touch Bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, touch-id

I received my new MacBook Pro with Touch Bar today and quickly realized that the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>power</kbd> (documented [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) under 'Sleep, log out, and shut down shortcuts') no longer works for quitting all apps followed by shutting down.

Can this shortcut be reinstated or is it replaced by something similar?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. In System Preferences → Mission Control

   - Change "Show Desktop" to F10
   - Change "Show Dashboard" to F11
2. In System Preferences → Keyboard, open App Shortcuts.

   1. Click + to add a new shortcut.
   2. Leave Application as "All Applications".
   3. In Menu Title enter exactly this phrase (without quotation marks): "Shut Down…"
   4. Click cursor in the Keyboard shortcut field, then on keyboard hold "fn" key then select "F12" on Touch Bar

- Holding "fn" key and selecting "F12" on Touch Bar will bring up the shutdown prompt.
- Holding "fn" key and selecting "F10" will show desktop, holding "F11" will show dashboard.

Comment: Out of curiosity I renamed the Menu Title "Shut Down" without the trailing ellipses. When I tried this "new" shortcut it immediately powered off the computer without any prompt. I can't view the Menu Title of the "Shut Down..." prompt though. Is there an advanced Mac OS tips and tricks resource I could peruse that goes more into detail regarding this kind of functionality?

Comment: I did some more research and came across the [macOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/TerminologyWording.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH15-SW3) which explains when and why ellipses should be used.

Comment: Thanks for this, I used the same method to programme Ctrl-F12 to prompt for restart.

Comment: Nice! Is there also a way to get the dialogue where it asks if I want to Reboot, Sleep, or Shutdown?

Answer (score 5):

*"Have you tried using TOUCH ID as a substitute for Power Button in the regular shortcuts?"*

holding down Touch ID will power off the computer, but it's a hard poweroff similar to holding down the power button on older machines for 5 seconds. I also can find no method for using the keyboard to initiate a normal shutdown. Bizarrely, the TouchBar has a sleep command that can be configured (see the bit about customize and expand [here](https://9to5mac.com/2016/11/18/15-touch-bar-tips-and-tricks-for-the-new-macbook-pro-video/)), but using modifier keys with the Touchbar sleep command like cmd or cmd-opt or cmd-opt-ctr will launch into the Energy Saver pane in System Preferences rather than sleep, restart or shut down..weird. Hopefully they'll add/fix this in a future software update. This is a BIG drawback for me as well in the new machine :(

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to make a QuickAction-Button. If you have quickActions on your TouchBar (to activate, look at apple guide [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/use-quick-action-workflows-aut73234890a/mac), you can use Automator to run a AppleScript (I used [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8263239) one) and insert it into the TouchBar. 
I made myself a nice red Button, as explained in detail [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251390862).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using TOUCH ID as a substitute for Power Button in the regular shortcuts?
I haven't got my hands on the new MBP but [an article here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/10/27/apples-new-macbook-pro-has-no-power-button-this-is-how-you-turn-it-on-and-off/) says

> ...and when you want to turn it off, you just hold down the Touch ID button found at the rightmost side of the Touch Bar.
>   So technically, Touch ID is the power button.

However, according to [iMore](http://www.imore.com/how-use-touch-id-your-macbook-pro), TOUCH ID only offers following functionality:

> The "Use Touch ID for" options include:
>   Unlocking your Mac
>   Apple Pay
>   iTunes & App Store

So ther is slightly less chance of Touch ID working as a power button.
You can let us know about it.
Another small workaround this situation can be using `CMD+Shift+/` to open `Help` menu first
[image: Help Menu]
And then using Direction keys (Up, Down, Left & Right) to navigate to Apple Menu, from where you can easily `Sleep`, `Restart` or `Shut Down`
[image: Apple Menu]

Comment: '_Have you tried using TOUCH ID as a substitute for Power Button in the regular shortcuts?_' Yes, that was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately, it has no effect whatsoever. Of course, I can press and hold TouchID for a hard shutdown, but that's not what I want. I want macOS to close all applications first (and ask about unsaved changes, if any) before powering down.

Answer (score -2):

You can press down the Touch ID button just as you would a regular Power button.
And thus the Control + Command + Touch ID does work if you hold it for 5 seconds or so.

Comment: That‘s a hard shutdown, works without Ctrl and Cmd and not what I’m asking for.